# Java GridLayout

Tags: java, grid-layout

Is there a way to add elements to a gridlayout that adds them horizontally instead of vertically? Basically i want to fill up an entire row with elements before it begins with the next.

Hope i made my question clear.

Comment: This is the way a GridLayout works. Each column is filled up before the next row is started. Unless of course you specify a single column, in which case all the components are added below one another. If you need more help post your SSCCE. (http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest [GridBagLayout](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) and [GridBagConstraints](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html)

It's a lot like a GridLayout, but with GridBagConstraints you can specify the x and y coordinates of the component, and you can do column and row spans.

It would look something like this:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JLabel label = new JLabel("foo");

panel.setLayout(layout);

c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
panel.add(label, c);
```

Comment: This looks like something really usefull. Is the x and y the location of the cell in the "table"?

Comment: Yep, it's the cell's coordinates.  Not the pixel coordinates of the container.

Comment: Works like a charm. I have a for loop where i set the x and y before adding each element. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

That *is* [how GridLayout works](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html).

Answer (score 0):

The GridLayout, as the name suggests lays out components according to the number of columns and rows you specified in the [constructor](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html#GridLayout), and will move to the next row as soon as you have added the specified number of components.

From your question, it seems that a [FlowLayout](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) is more along the lines of what you're looking for.

**Edit**: I'm not sure why, but if you specify the number of rows as 0 (e.g. `new GridLayout(0, 9)`, it seems to work properly.

Comment: well, i tried adding 5 texfields to a 9x9 gridlayout, and the are on top of each other, not side by side. So it fills up a coloumn first, and then the moves on to the next coloumn, what I i want is filling up rows first :D

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant to say that you want to fill up all the rows in a column before moving to the next column. If so, then use a custom layout manager

[VerticalGridLayout](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=5716765&)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should use [GroupLayout](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.html)  It's new (since jdk 1.6) and pretty awesome. It gives you a ton of flexibility in layout.